# Jump search algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement jump search in python.

here is the code

```
'''
2 jump search
'''
import math
def jump_search(arr,search):
    interval = int(math.sqrt(len(arr)))
    for i in range(0,len(arr),interval):
        if arr[i] >  search:
            chunk = i
            break
        if arr[i] ==  search:
            return i
    arr_ls = arr[chunk-interval:chunk]
    ind = [i for i,d in enumerate(arr_ls) if d==search]
    return chunk-interval+ind[0]
arr = [ i for i in range(1,200,15)]

res = jump_search(arr, 121)
print(res)
```

here is the problems I am facing  :

1. last chunk is skipping
2. Improved version ?
   Also i dont think my code clean and short

Comment: Please read [ask], Not everyone wants to follow the link, so include all necessary information in your question with an example of the desired  input /output

Comment: ignore the link, I think I have added all information

Comment: Which inputs don't work?

Comment: last element of list `196`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presently, if the `search` variable is present in the last chunk, then chunk won't be initialized. And hence, you must be getting an error. So why don't you check for the last interval specifically. I have added a `flag` variable which checks for that. If chunk is found, well and good, otherwise we have to see the last interval.

```
import math
def jump_search(arr,search):
    flag = 0
    interval = int(math.sqrt(len(arr)))
    for i in range(0,len(arr),interval):
        if arr[i] >  search:
            chunk = i
            flag = 1
            break
        if arr[i] ==  search:
            return i
    if flag==0:
        c=i
        for j in arr[i:]:
            if j==search:
                return c
            c+=1
    else:
        arr_ls = arr[chunk-interval:chunk]
        ind = [i for i,d in enumerate(arr_ls) if d==search]
        return chunk-interval+ind[0]
arr = [ i for i in range(1,200,15)]
res = jump_search(arr, 196)
print(res) 
# prints 13
```

Also, you won't have to do all this, if you keep track of the `lower bound` instead of the `upper bound` which you are doing now. So to make you code better, which you asked for, try this:

```
import math
def jump_search(arr,search):
    low = 0
    interval = int(math.sqrt(len(arr)))
    for i in range(0,len(arr),interval):
        if arr[i] < search:
            low = i
        elif arr[i] == search:
            return i
        else:
            break # bigger number is found
    c=low
    for j in arr[low:]:
        if j==search:
            return c
        c+=1
    return "Not found"

arr = [ i for i in range(1,200,15)]
res = jump_search(arr, 196)
print(res)
# prints 13
```

Comment: Perfect, really helpful. I like the second method (the improvised)

Comment: a small suggestion, if the number is found at early stage the `arr[low:]` will take all elements till the end, I suggest you to use `arr[low:low+interval]` to restrict and save time.

Comment: Both answers are perfect, hard to decide which is correct :(

Comment: @TarunK You are right, but I think you are not realising the fact that the loop will only run for at max `interval -1` times, isn't it? So, there is no efficiency optimization when you use `arr[low:low+interval]` instead of `arr[low:]`. Both are ok.

Comment: Absoulty correct, May be it's because I used list comprehension. If I want to search 16 ( which is at index 1 ), `arr[low:low+interval] ` will give me [16, 31, 46, 61] ( 4 linerar searches will perform ) whereas in `arr[low:]` ( 18 linerar searches will perform ).

Comment: @TarunK You are wrong Tarun. Didn't you notice the `return` statement? It will come out of the function as soon as the result is found. So number of searches in either case is just 1.

Comment: Try searching any number, which is not in list

Comment: @Miraj50 IMO, a good response should include the correction of such vulnerabilities. The OP could simply not take this into account

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov Okay I have edited to account for that also. TarunK, Have a look at the second answer (the better one), it also handles the cases where the number is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Your code skips last chunk, because step of for loop is greater than last chunk length. Also it would fail if you try search element which is not in list.

In summary - this should work for you:

```
import math


def jump_search(arr, search):
    interval = int(math.sqrt(len(arr)))
    i = 0
    # set i to zero if list is empty
    for i in range(0, len(arr), interval):
        if arr[i] > search:
            break
        if arr[i] == search:
            return i
    else:
        # if loop exited normaly - add interval to i, so last chuck is included too
        i += interval

    last_chunk = arr[i - interval:i]

    # iterate directly and simply break if item found
    for ind, val in enumerate(last_chunk):
        if val == search:
            break
    else:
        # if loop exited normaly - item not found in chunk
        # return None instead of index
        return None
    return i - interval + ind
```

Comment: Thanks, `i += interval` solved my problem :) . One thing is just making me uncomfortable is suppose my interval is 4 and last chunk contains only 2 elements therefore my `i+4` which will take extra indexed, however python handles it smoothly

Comment: Both answers are perfect, hard to decide which is correct :(

Comment: @TarunK you could try: `[1,2,3][:10]` for example and see that nothing bad happens. Slicing is safe. It will cause no errors assuming you use integers as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be considered (not exactly an improvement) but as an alternate to the above code?

```
def jumpSearch(a,m,x):
    for i in range(0,len(a),m):
        if a[i]==x:
           return i
        elif a[i]>x:
           high = i
           break

    for j in range(high,high-m,-1):
        if a[j]==x:
           return j
```